# Multiple regex extract from a text R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr, alphanumeric

I have the following df

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c('Label issues as ISS101  and ISS 201 on label 23 with x203 17','issue as ISS5051 with label 01 as l018','there is nothing here')
```

I want to extract & create the following data frame from the df

```
id  iss     label  ext1 ext2
 1  ISS101  23     x203  17
 1  ISS201  23     x203  17
 2  ISS5051 01     l018  NA
 3    NA    NA      NA   NA
```

The length of iss can vary as seen in the example. It may or may not have a space between "ISS" & the subsequent digits, again this is visible in the e.g.
The length of label, ext1 & ext2 are fixed.
I have tried various possibilities with regex using stringr & dplyr. But none of these are close to the solution & hence worth mentioning here. Looking forward for help, let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` and `stringr` like this...

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(iss=str_extract_all(str_replace_all(text,"ISS\\s+(\\d+)","ISS\\1"),
                        "ISS\\d+"), #remove spaces and then extract ISSnnn
                 label=str_match(text,"label\\s+(\\d+)")[,2], #extract label + nn
                 ext1=str_match(text,"label\\s+\\d+.*?([a-z]\\d+)")[,2], #extract Xnnn after label
                 ext2=str_match(text,"\\s(\\d+)$")[,2]) %>% #extract digits at end of string
              unnest(iss) %>% #unnest iss (creates one row for each iss)
              select(iss,label,ext1,ext2) #select wanted variables

df2

      iss label ext1 ext2
1  ISS101    23 x203   17
2  ISS201    23 x203   17
3 ISS5051    01 l018 <NA>
```

Comment: works!! Taking nothing away, Could you recommend a regex cheat sheet? Have been using the one from Rstudio

Comment: @Param I tend to use this one when I get stuck... http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is great IMO, you can directly+interactively test your expressions too

Answer (score 0):

This might be a start:

```
do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, 
  lapply(df$text, function(x) {
    as.data.frame(cbind(
      iss = unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(ISS\\s?\\d{3,4})")),
      label = unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?<=label)\\s?(\\d{1,2})")),
      ext1 = unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "((x|l)\\d{3})")),
      ext2 = unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "(?<=x|l\\d{3})\\s?\\d{1,3}"))
    ))}
    ))

      iss label ext1 ext2
1  ISS101    23 x203  203
2 ISS 201    23 x203  203
3 ISS5051    01 l018 <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done the best I can based on your description. Without seeing more data, I can't guarantee that this will be generalizable, but it produces the desired output for the df you provided, so it should be a good start.

```
# create data frame
df = data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text = c('Label issues as ISS101  and ISS 201 on label 23 with x203 17','issue as ISS5051 with label 01 as l018','there is nothing here'))

# parse text into fields
df <- df %>% mutate(
    iss = str_extract(text, "ISS\\d+\\D"),
    iss_space = str_extract(text, "ISS\\s\\d+\\D"),
    label = str_extract(text, "label.+\\D"), 
    label = str_extract(label, "\\d+\\D"),
    ext1 = str_extract(text, "\\s\\D\\d{3}"),
    ext2 = str_extract(text, "\\s\\D\\d{3}\\s\\d{2}"),
    ext2 = str_extract(ext2, "\\s\\d{2}")) 

# clean up into correct format
df <- df %>%
   gather(iss, iss_space, key = "type", value = "iss") %>%
    select(-text, -type) %>% 
    distinct() %>%
    filter(!(duplicated(id) == T & is.na(iss) == T)) %>%
    arrange(id) %>%
    select(id, iss, label, ext1, ext2) %>%
    mutate(iss = str_replace_all(iss, " ", ""))

df

  id     iss label  ext1 ext2
1  1  ISS101   23   x203   17
2  1  ISS201   23   x203   17
3  2 ISS5051   01   l018 <NA>
4  3    <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```